# How to speed up the execution for the below code snippet

Tags: java, multithreading, performance, file

my objective is : I want to read a file for specific text and i want to find that text in other directory/sub directory  containing all the files.But currently program execution is very slow. i ran the program many times to check the performance. i am currently using jdk1.6 in my system. Could any one please improve the execution time or guide how to get better performance?

```
  import java.io.BufferedReader;
    import java.io.File;
    import java.io.FileReader;
    import java.io.IOException;
    import java.util.ArrayList;
    import java.util.Arrays;
    import java.util.List;
    import java.util.Scanner;


    public class ActionFinder {
        private static final String FILENAME = "D:\\WorkSpace\\data\\Navigation.properties";
        private static ArrayList<String> allAbsoluteFilePathList = new ArrayList<String>();
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        BufferedReader br = null;
        FileReader fr = null;
        try {
            fr = new FileReader(FILENAME);
            br = new BufferedReader(fr);
            String sCurrentLine;
            ArrayList<String> actionList = new ArrayList<String>(); 


            while ((sCurrentLine = br.readLine()) != null) {

                String cmdString = sCurrentLine;

                  if(cmdString.contains(".Commands")){
                      String[] output = cmdString.split("\\.Commands");
                      actionList.add("Action."+output[0]); 

                  }

            }

              listAllTheFile("D:\\dev\\vob002\\IB\\war\\src\\main\\webapp\\web\\L001\\corporate");

            //here we are finding all the actions one by one from the file list
            for(int i=0; i < actionList.size(); i++){
                String actionName= actionList.get(i);
                searchAction(allAbsoluteFilePathList, actionName);
            }



        } catch (Exception e) {
            System.out.println("Error2: " + e.toString());

        } finally {
            try {
                if (br != null)
                    br.close();

                if (fr != null)
                    fr.close();

            } catch (Exception ex) {
                System.out.println("Error3: " + ex.toString());

            }

        }
    }


    private static void searchAction(ArrayList<String> allAbsoluteFilePathList, String actionName) {
        try {

          if(null !=allAbsoluteFilePathList){
              for(int i=0; i < allAbsoluteFilePathList.size(); i++){

                  final Scanner scanner = new Scanner(new File(allAbsoluteFilePathList.get(i)));
                  while (scanner.hasNextLine()) {
                     final String lineFromFile = scanner.nextLine();
                     if(lineFromFile.contains(actionName)) { 
                         // a match!
                         System.out.println("I found " +actionName+ " in file " + allAbsoluteFilePathList.get(i));
                         break;
                     }
                  }
              } 

          }




          }catch (Exception e) {
             System.out.println("Error1: " + e.toString());

        }

    }


    private static List<File> listAllTheFile(String directoryName) {
        File directory = new File(directoryName);
        List<File> resultList = new ArrayList<File>();

        File[] fList = directory.listFiles();
        resultList.addAll(Arrays.asList(fList));

        for (File file : fList) {

            if (file.isFile()) {
                allAbsoluteFilePathList.add(file.getAbsolutePath());
            } else if (file.isDirectory()) {
                resultList.addAll(listAllTheFile(file.getAbsolutePath()));
            }
        }

        return resultList;
    }

    }
```

Comment: you could start with updating your jdk

Comment: Use profiling to find where the code is spending the majority of its time, and take action accordingly.  Invocation counts will help too, chances are you have an n-squared algorithm in there somewhere.

Comment: @Stultuske depending upon his situation, he may have no control over his environment. Also that may not necessarily improve the perf.

Answer (score 1):

As already said in the comments try to find out where your performance is lost by using a profile. Independent from that here are some points that can be improved (not necessarily performance related, but still... ;-):

```
fr = new FileReader(FILENAME);
br = new BufferedReader(fr);
```

Don't use `FileReader` but open a file like this:

```
fr = new InputStreamReader(new FileInputStream(FILENAME), "8859_1");
br = new BufferedReader(fr);
```

`FileReader` uses the system's charset to convert the content to text which might not be the charset your file is encoded.

```
if (cmdString.contains(".Commands")){
    String[] output = cmdString.split("\\.Commands");
    actionList.add("Action."+output[0]); 
}
```

You're calling `contains` and create a regular expression doing essentially the same thing. split creates and compiles the Pattern each time you do the splitting. All this can be handled by working with Regular Expressions directly. If you compile the `Pattern` outside the loop, this should help improve performance, since it's only done once and not n-times.

```
} catch (Exception e) {
    System.out.println("Error1: " + e.toString());
}
```

This is not helpful in case an exception is thrown, in general you need the complete stacktrace, so `e.printStackTrace()` is to be preferred if you really have to output the error.

Answer (score 1):

Try something like this:

```
public class ActionFinder
{
   private static final String FILENAME = "D:/WorkSpace/data/Navigation.properties";
   private static List<String> allAbsoluteFilePathList = new ArrayList<>();
   public static void main(String[] args)
   {
      try (final BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(
                                     new FileInputStream(FILENAME), "UTF-8")))
      {
          List<String> actionList = new ArrayList<>(); 
          while (true) // infinte loop
          {
             final String sCurrentLine = br.readLine()
             if (null == sCurrentLine)
             {
                break; // leave the loop at the end of file
             }
             else
             {
                // indexOf and substring is faster than parsing a RegEx and then
                // instantiating an array of String objects...
                final int pos = sCurrentLine.indexOf(".Commands");
                if (pos >= 0)
                {
                   actionList.add("Action." + sCurrentLine.substring(0, pos)); 
                }
             }
          }
          listAllTheFile(new File("D:/dev/vob002/IB/war/src/main/webapp/web/L001/corporate")
                             .getAbsoulteFile());
          // here we are finding all the actions one by one from the file list
          for(final String actionName : actionList)
          {
             searchAction(allAbsoluteFilePathList, actionName);
          }
      }
      catch (Exception e)
      {
         e.printStackTrace();
      }
   }

   private static void searchAction(List<String> allAbsoluteFilePathList, String actionName)
   {
      if (null != allAbsoluteFilePathList)
      {
         // Entering/leaving a TRY block uses resources, so placing it inside the if
        // statement seems logical...
         try
         {
            for(final String absFilePath : allAbsoluteFilePathList)
            {
               final Scanner scanner = new Scanner(new File(absFilePath));
               while (scanner.hasNextLine())
               {
                  final String lineFromFile = scanner.nextLine();
                  if(lineFromFile.contains(actionName))
                  { 
                     // a match!
                     // printf is faster than String + String...
                     // Also, allAbsoluteFilePathList.get() is only called once...
                     System.out.printf("I found %s in file %s%n", actionName, absFilePath);
                     break;
                  }
               }
            }
         }
         catch (Exception e)
         {
            e.printStackTrace();
         }
      }
   }

   // The return value of this result, a collection was never used...
   // Changed it to not return anything.
   private static void listAllTheFile(File directory)
   {
      final File[] fList = directory.listFiles();
      for (final File file : fList)
      {
         if (file.isFile())
         {
            // As the root call is made with an absolute path, it is not necessary to call
            // getAbsolutePath every time...
            allAbsoluteFilePathList.add(file.getPath());
         }
         else if (file.isDirectory())
         {
            // As the argument is changed to File, do not need to call getAbsolutePath
            // method on the recursion...
            listAllTheFile(file);
         }
      }
   }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you:

1. Find all the actions in a file.
2. For each action you found:

   1. Search a list of files.
   2. For each line in each file:

      1. If the action appears in the line, do something.

You would do MUCH better doing something like:

1. Find all the actions in a file.
2. Search a list of files.

   1. For each line in each file:

      1. For each action you found:

         1. If one of your actions appears in the line, do something.

The primary benefit here is that you are only searching through this list of files once.